# Why does Puck refer to Emilia as 'My Daughter'?

Tags: re-zero

In episode 15, Puck referred to Emilia as his Daughter.

Why is this? A few thoughts I have come up with to explain the reasoning come down to:

- They have a relationship like Father/Daughter. (In my opinion they do not have this, they seem more like best friends than this.)
- Puck IS her father. (Again, this seems convoluted to me, as it is stated that Puck is a Spirit.
- the 'Daughter' terminology is code for something else, Emilia likely having something like this for Puck too.

It is also said by Puck in episode 18 something along the lines of "In accordance with my contract, I shall now destroy the world".

When asked why, the answer given was "Emilia is my entire reason for existing. There is no reason for me to exist in a world without her."

This shows some kind of deeper bond between them, deeper than I can think.

What exactly *is* their relationship?

Comment: I don't think it's been revealed in manga yet, but I'm pretty sure you can read manga chapters corresponding to upcoming episodes and learn from there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Puck is a spirit contracted to Emilia.

His identity was revealed during the royal election speech,
where during her speech (which was shortened in the anime) Roswaal provoked Subaru to instigate a few of the elders and the knights for her being a half-elf with silver hair.

Puck, sensing danger and Emilia's distraught, appeared and threatened to freeze the whole court.

The elder stopped his ruckus after seeing and recognizing who Puck was: one of the Four Great Spirits (in term of being old and powerful), the Beast of
the end of the Eternally Frozen Land who was created to destroy the world (there are many biblical comparisons in the series, the title basically makes him a comparison to the four horseman of the apocalypse).

A few years before the series began, Puck found a young Emilia and decided to stop his intended plan in destroying the world and care for her by making a pact/contract with her. Thus accidentally stopping the world destruction by him.

For seven years, Puck cared for Emilia like a father, choosing her clothing, hairstyle, speech and manners like a father would. The 7am-5pm appearance was also just part of the contract, as you can see in episode 18 that he appears at night.

The death of Emilia causes Puck to continue what he is destined to do: to destroy the world, knowing, however, that Reinhardt the current master swordsman will end him if not the Royal Protector Dragon, Volcanica.

Comment: If you could edit that answer as to where it explains in enough detail for someone as dense as myself to understand, I will accept it, however as it stands, it's simply not really enough for me to do so.
I don't have the motivation, nor time/money to buy the novels/Manga, so an explanation of what happens, spoiler or not would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the role of Reinhard more clearly here ? His background isn't shown much in the anime. Just what is his role ?

Comment: @Jarvis Reinhardt Van Astrea came from a long line of chosen/special family the Van Astrea that is able to carry a powerful sword granted to the first of their name Reid van Astrea by Volcanica the Dragon .The ability to carry and wield the sword alone is a blessing from the World called "The Blessing of the Sword Saints/Kensei (yen press decided to call them Master Swordsman)" . Some of the Sword Saints are also given extra blessing like Reinhardt predecessor Theresia who is given "Blessing of The Reaper" where wounds that is given can never be healed unless the inflictor allow it.

Comment: Reinhardt is even more special he had more than 1000 in counting compared to his grandmother.example when fighting Elsa, Emilia cant tag team with Reinhardt since the spirit is more attracted to him due to one of his blessing making emilia unable to use her power. Only one Van Astrea can wield the Sword. The Rights to Wield the Weapon is given to the next generation when the chosen van Astrea is given his/her first blessings

Comment: Basically Reinhardt and the Other Sword Saints can be considered a walking and Talking Tactical Nuke when the country has an unsolvable problem they sent him. the Witch Cult avoid dealing with him

Answer (score 1):

In the second movie, the story of Emilia's childhood is shown. After they defeated Melakuera, she told Puck "You're my father now", and Puck laughed.